# Passing List as Parameter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a list this.

```
[Attachments(filename=a.json,  id=ATT-mXRJB-BmVzs, contentType=application/json),
 Attachments(filename=b.pdf,  id=ATT-y7Qr2-8RqkW, contentType=application/pdf ),
 Attachments(filename=c.docx,  id=ATT-mYh3z-3YJ37, contentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)]
```

I need to iterate and get ids from this list and pass each id  as parameter for an API call - attachments/{{attachmentid}}/retrieve .

I am able to retrieve ids and store them in a Map . (Not sure if  using Map is correct here?)
This is the code snippet I have written , But I am unable to proceed after that.

```
  Map<String, String> attachmentMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Optional.ofNullable(attList)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .forEach(aList -> {
                     attachmentMap.put("id", aList.getId());
                    LOGGER.debug("Attachment ids : {}",attachmentMap);
                });
```

2020-08-27 22:21:49.967 DEBUG 18644 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.f.p.h.s.i.PlServiceImpl   : Attachment ids : {id=ATT-mXRJB-BmVzs}
2020-08-27 22:21:49.967 DEBUG 18644 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.f.p.h.s.i.PlServiceImpl   : Attachment ids : {id=ATT-y7Qr2-8RqkW}
2020-08-27 22:21:49.967 DEBUG 18644 --- [nio-8081-exec-2] c.f.p.h.s.i.PlServiceImpl   : Attachment ids : {id=ATT-mYh3z-3YJ37}

```
  URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.
                    .pathSegment(ATTACHMENTS)
                    .pathSegment(?)   //what to give here? 
                    .pathSegment(RETRIEVE)
                    .build().toUri();
        LOGGER.debug("URL to Retrieve  : {}", uri.toString());
```

I am able to print attachment ids - but how do I pass each of them as parameter to an api call like this  - attachments/{{attachmentid}}/retrieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use foreach to iterate through map and call the http call method

```
Map<String, String> attachmentMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Optional.ofNullable(attList)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList())
                .forEach(aList -> {
                     attachmentMap.put("id", aList.getId());
                     httpCall(aList.getId());
                    LOGGER.debug("Attachment ids : {}",attachmentMap);
                });
```

create Http call method with parameter id(also other params you need) and use method to call.

```
public static void httpCall(id){
  URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.
                    .pathSegment(ATTACHMENTS)
                    .pathSegment(id)   //what to give here? 
                    .pathSegment(RETRIEVE)
                    .build().toUri();
        LOGGER.debug("URL to Retrieve  : {}", uri.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just loop over `Attachments` list directly and retrieve the id from each `Attachment` and pass it to the UriComponentsBuilder to build the URI. You don't need an extra data structure to hold the Ids.

```
List<URI> uriList = new ArrayList<>();

for(Attachment attachment: Attachments){
   String id = attachment.getId();
   if (id != null) {
       URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder.
                .pathSegment(ATTACHMENTS)
                .pathSegment(id)
                .pathSegment(RETRIEVE)
                .build().toUri();
       uriList.add(uri); // or you can call the uri directly from here using your http client.
   }
}
```